# How to combine multiple (3+) bands (filters) to a single color image?

Tags: colors, python-imaging-library, rgb

I have the same image (fits format) in multiple bands (filters: blue_light, blue_dark, pink, green, yellow, orange, red), seven in total.
I would like to combine it in the single color image.

I know how to do it with 3 bands:

```
img_rgb = numpy.zeros((stamp_size, stamp_size, 3))
img_rgb[:,:,0] = numpy.flip(stamp_red_darker,0)
img_rgb[:,:,1] = numpy.flip(stamp_green_lighter,0)
img_rgb[:,:,2] = numpy.flip(stamp_blue,0)

imb_rgb_png=Image.fromarray(img_rgb.astype('uint8'),mode='RGB')
```

But how can I do it with 7?

Comment: It depends what your aim is. You can make multiple images by selecting different combinations of bands. Or you could maybe use *”Principal Component Analysis”* as a form of dimensionality reduction to select the three principal components containing the most variance and use them as your RGB channels.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, your output will have only three color bands. This means that you need to define a function how you want to combine your bands into a red channel, a green channel and a blue channel. This is probably a linear combination of the seven bands you have.

```
red_channel = alpha_bl * blue_light + alpha_bd * blue_dark + alpha_p * pink + alpha_g * green + alpha_y * yellow + alpha_o * orange + alpha_r * red
green_channel = beta_bl * blue_light + ...
red_channel = gamma_bl * blue_light + ...
```

The values for these alpha's, beta's and gamma's are up to you to decide. Depending on where these channels are coming from, perhaps there is already some documentation how they should be combined?